# How do I interact with a map like Google Maps or OpenStreetMaps with Playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I've been attempting to use Playwright to interact with the map component of sites like Google Maps or OpenStreetMaps. I've tried using the combination of browser.mouse.move(), browser.mouse.up(), and browser.mouse.down() with literals as the parameters. When I run it, it doesn't seem to be doing anything with the map at all.

Is there a way to move the map around with Playwright?

I've created a GitHub repo so that it can be reproduced easily. I will also have the code down below.
https://github.com/vincent-woodward/Playwright-Map-Interaction

```
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  //await page.goto("https://www.google.com/maps");
  await page.goto("https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/38.01/-95.84");

  await page.mouse.move(600, 300);
  await page.mouse.down();
  await page.mouse.move(1200, 450);
  await page.mouse.up();

  browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I have tried the same thing and can not get it to work.  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that if you add `{steps: 5}` to the move command then it will work as expected.  I think something about the moving map interfaces of openstreet maps and also leaflet expect there to be a sequence of mouse move events.

```
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

(async () => {
   const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
   const page = await browser.newPage();

   //await page.goto("https://www.google.com/maps");
   await page.goto("https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/38.01/-95.84");

   await page.mouse.move(600, 300);
   await page.mouse.down();
   await page.mouse.move(1200, 450, {steps: 5});  // <-- Change here
   await page.mouse.up();

   browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 5):

Great news! It looks like this was [freshly added about a day ago!](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1094#ref-commit-8960584)

[View source/test implementation](https://github.com/JoelEinbinder/playwright-1/blob/2a790436a5163bb4ae51c8cbf52ad09a3fe83663/tests/page/page-drag.spec.ts#L169-L173)

After looking at the PR, your code should work:

```js
await page.mouse.move(600, 300);
await page.mouse.down();
await page.mouse.move(1200, 450); // NOTE: make sure your viewport is big enough for this
await page.mouse.up();
```

Comment: I'm still having some trouble with it. I'm failing to see how this would work for a map. In Google maps for instance you can select the map for the first time hover is used but there wouldn't be a selector that I would be able to use as a target for the second time that hover is used. I'm probably missing something but how would I drag the map with these methods then?

Comment: Updated for clarity, with a note about viewport size.

Comment: This did not work for me.  See my answer below about what ended up working correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Allen, I tested on an image dragging interface... Maps w/ animated dragging & async resource loading might need that {steps: 5} bit.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on a laptop. You can also remove the loops for the delay

```
const { chromium } = require("playwright");
(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
 //await page.goto("https://www.google.com/maps");
  await page.goto("https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/38.01/-95.84");

  await page.click('#map',{force:true});//here the trick
  await page.mouse.down();

  await page.mouse.move(890, 80);
  for(var i = 0;i<1000000000;i++){}
  await page.mouse.move(400, 180); 
  for(var i = 0;i<1000000000;i++){}
  await page.mouse.move(700, 300); 

  await page.mouse.up();
//browser.close();
})();
```